# arquillian UnsupportedOperationException when use InSequence annotation

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

I get the error when I add `@InSequence` annotation to my tests:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException   at
>   java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList$1.set(Collections.java:1412)
>     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:234)     at
>   org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.getChildren(Arquillian.java:71)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getFilteredChildren(ParentRunner.java:426)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:351)
>     at org.junit.runners.Suite.describeChild(Suite.java:123)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.IdeaSuite.describeChild(IdeaSuite.java:68)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.IdeaSuite.getChildren(IdeaSuite.java:85)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getFilteredChildren(ParentRunner.java:426)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:379)     at
>   org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.apply(Filter.java:97)    at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:37)

When I run tests without this annotation all goes ok. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in JUnit. I used version 4.12-beta-1 which returns unmodifiable list in this method:

```
public List<FrameworkMethod> getAnnotatedMethods(
        Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(getAnnotatedMembers(methodsForAnnotations, annotationClass, false));
}
```

Class `org.junit.runners.model.TestClass`.

I downgraded to version JUnit 4.11 and all test was runned without problems with annotation @InSequence.

Answer (score 0):

The same with me. Even with the 4.12 final version of Junit. As workaround in my case I extend the Arquillian class and override the method getChildren. Then, the main difference is convert the unmodifiable colletion to a modified.