# JBoss Arquillian @InSequence with JUnit 4.12

Tags: java, junit, junit4, jboss-arquillian

I'm using `Arquillian: 1.1.5.Final` against the latest `JUnit: 4.12`. The test method which is annotated with `@InSequence` can not be used as the following exception.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList$1.set(Collections.java:1412)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:234)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.getChildren(Arquillian.java:73)
```

The other stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219233/arquillian-unsupportedoperationexception-when-use-insequence-annotation), also mentions about this error. Sadly the answer is back to use `JUnit: 4.11` instead. Furthermore I also found the Arquiilian Issue: [ARQ-1835](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1835). Again there is no any activity yet. I've tried to post to the Arquiliian discussion forum [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/250851) which seems no activity as well.

Could you please help to advise the workaround for solving this issue?

Comment: Sorry for irrelevant question, but: what features come with `JUnit 4.12` that cause of your unwillingness to downgrade JUnit?

Comment: It's fine. I'm using the JUnit 4.12 for non-production project with purpose to POC and learning the new feature. There are some good feature at 4.12 which may safe my time.

Comment: So far I can make some tweak to the `org.junit.runners.model.TestClass` to revert that `UnmodifiableList` to the `simple list`. But it should not be a solution.

Comment: Have you considered providing a pull request to fix the issue? It may be as simple as making a copy of the list before sorting it. Looks like the code is at https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/blob/master/junit/core/src/main/java/org/jboss/arquillian/junit/Arquillian.java

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that the Arquillian team has fixed the issue. I've tested against it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in Arquillian. See [this commit](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/commit/c104d4484f3f786376d5816b04bc58b31a528c29).

To fix this issue, upgrade to Arquillian 1.1.6 or later.